# python AttributeError while trying to send an email

Tags: python, python-3.x

this python script is made to send an email using anonymouse:

```
import mechanicalsoup

if __name__ == "__main__":

    URL = "http://anonymouse.org/anonemail.html"
    RECIPIENT = "javaisnotbad@gmail.com"
    SUBJECT = "test python"
    MESSAGE = "salut"

    browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()

    emailpage = browser.get(URL)

    emailpage.find("input", {"name": "session[To:]"})["value"] = RECIPIENT
    emailpage.find("input", {"name": "session[Subject:]"})["value"] = SUBJECT
    emailpage.find("input", {"name": "session[Message:]"})["value"] = MESSAGE

    browser.submit(emailpage)
```

When I run the program, I get this error :

```
emailpage.find("input", {"name": "session[To:]"})["value"] = RECIPIENT
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I Dont understand the problem, if anyone could help. Please understand I am a beginner.

Comment: https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html look at the "get_current_page()" section

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code. Post the code here, as text

Comment: So, to help you understand the error, it's telling you that the `mechanicalsoup.Browser()` item does not have a find method. You may want to check if it's coming back as `None`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EEh9JEeM is the code, I cant post the code on the websites it never works so I use this

Comment: click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52372874/edit) and copy/paste the code into the question, select all the code and press `Ctrl+K` or `{}` the code formatting button

Comment: you might want to try something like `emailpage.soup.find()`

Comment: @davedwards thanks didnt know how to poste codes like this. emailpage.soup.find doesnt work either : "emailpage.soup.find("input", {"name": "session[To:]"})["value"] = RECIPIENT
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: @RollandMartin that's because the string you are searching for, `"input"`, does not exist in the HTML of the website. Try `print emailpage.soup.prettify()` and see the content

Comment: @davedwards doesnt the program just looks for "To:", "Subject" and "Message" ? I modified this program and I didnt understand it all : https://piratefache.ch/python-3-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/

Comment: oh I get it its a really bad mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

had to rebuild it all using models on internet : here is the fixed code!

```
import mechanicalsoup

RECIPIENT = "email to send the message to"
SUBJECTT = "the subject" 
MESSAGE = "your message"


browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("http://anonymouse.org/anonemail.html")

#print(browser.get_url())

browser.select_form('form[action="cgi-bin/anon-email.cgi"]')

browser["to"] = RECIPIENT
browser["subject"] = SUBJECTT
browser["text"] = MESSAGE

browser.submit_selected()
```